# How to set color when calling printf in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64

I want to set the color when I call `printf` from assembly.

This is my code:

```
Out:    
    mov     rdi, answer
    mov     rsi, r10
    mov     rax,0
    call    printf
section .data
    answer:     db       "\033[0;31m%d\033[0m",10,0
```

I use NASM to compile and gcc to link:

```
nasm -f elf64 "%f"
gcc -o %e %e.o
```

However, the output is:

```
\033[0;31m(my r10)\033[0m
```

Comment: thx MikeCAT!   Warn to others, use ` not '

Comment: There's nothing magic happening here.  You could have used `db 0o33, "[0;31m%d",  0o33, "[0m", 10, 0` to get the non-printable characters into your `.rodata` section the same way you use decimal `10` to get a newline and `0` to get a terminating byte.  (And octal 0o33 is 27 in decimal; you can write it any way that NASM supports).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `` ` `` for surrounding strings to have escape sequence work in NASM.

Reference: [3.4.2 Character Strings](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.12.01/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2)

Try this:

```
Out:
    mov     rdi, answer
    mov     rsi, r10
    mov     rax,0
    call    printf
section .data
    answer:     db       `\033[0;31m%d\033[0m`,10,0
```